# Is A is open/closed?

Tags: general-topology

let  $\{V_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be  sequence   of open and dense  subsets  of  $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. set $A= \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n$
then  A is

choose the correct option

$1.)$ open

$2.)$ closed

$3.)$ countable

$4.)$ uncountable

My attempt : I take $n = 1.$

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space, the Baire category theorem implies that $A$ is dense, in particular it is nonempty.
We also claim that $A$ has to be uncountable. Indeed, suppose that $A=\{x_1, x_2, \ldots \}$ was countable, and define the sets $W_n := \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \{x_n\}$. Then clearly each $W_n$ is an open dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and thus applying the Baire category theorem to the countably many sets $V_n,W_n$ yields that $\bigcap_{n \geq 1} (V_n \cap W_n)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, in particular it is nonempty. On the other hand
$$ \bigcap_{n \geq 1} (V_n \cap W_n) = \left(\bigcap_{n \geq 1} V_n \right) \cap \left( \bigcap_{n \geq 1} W_n  \right) = A \cap (\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \cup_{n \geq 1} \{ x_n \} ) = A \cap (\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus A) = \emptyset.$$
This is a contradiction, so $A$ is uncountable.

Im confusing that   A  must  be   open?

Any hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: $\mathbb N$ is the set of natural numbers. You can't just say $\mathbb N = 1.$

Comment: @D.Brogan  i  thinks  that doesn't  affect  anything  in my question  whether u take $1, 2$ or $ 3$

Comment: @D.Brogan . The proposer meant $n=1$. I am going to edit the Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $A$ doesn't have to be open. Let $\{q_n\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let $V_n=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{q_n\}$. Then $V_n$ is open and dense. But $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}V_n=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb Q$, which is not open.

Comment: so  A must  closed ?? its its  true ?

Comment: Of course not, unless each $V_n$ is equal to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: carlos  sir....im not getting   why directly    writes 
 $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}V_n=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb Q$ ? i mean   $\mathbb{Q}$  is closed   and complement  of closed is open

Comment: If $x\in\mathbb Q$, then $x=q_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. So $x\notin V_n$ and therefore $x\notin\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}V_n$. But if $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus Q$, then $x$ belongs to *each* $V_n$ and therefore to their intersection.

Comment: thanks u sir @Jose  carlos sir...actually    $\mathbb{R}  \setminus  \mathbb{Q}$ is neither  closed nor open......i  got its now

Comment: To the proposer: Most subsets of $\Bbb R$ are neither open nor closed. So if $ A $ is not open then it does not follow that $A$ is closed. Also $\Bbb Q$  is not closed in $\Bbb R$..... You have exactly the right idea for showing that $A$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $V_n =(-1/n,1/n)$, $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, open and dense subsets.

$A:=\displaystyle{\cap}_{n \in \mathbb {Z^+}} V_n= ${$0 $}.

Hence $A$ is not open.

Rule out option $1)$.

Note:  In this particular example  $A$ is closed.

This does not!!! Imply that option $2)$ is correct
(cf.Carlos' example).

Comment: that  mean  $A= 0$ is  closed??  is it??

Comment: Jasmine. Here : Complement of A= {0} open, hence A= {0} closed.

Comment: ..@Peter but  Jose  carlos  answer said that A  is neither closed nor open ?

Comment: Yes. is an example where $\cap V_n$ , $V_n$ dense and open, is 1) not open, in this!! special example turns out to be closed.

Comment: but i have proved A  is uncountable  ,then  how  A become  closed   as closed  can never  be  uncountable ?? is its ?

Comment: Jasmine.I am not a Topology buff. Carlos is.But the interval [0,1] is closed and uncountable.Is your proof correct? {0} is certainly countable(finite).